# Javascript function call context

Tags: javascript

I have this situation:

A JavaScript `function A(){}` and another`function B(){}`.

I call function A in two modes:

- as a parameter of function B -- `B(A());`
- in standalone form -- `A();`

Is there a way to sense in code when function A is evaluated as parameter and when is executed as standalone?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. Why would you want to do that?  What problem would that solve for you?  If you describe that problem, you're much more likely to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to sense in code when function A is evaluated as parameter and when is executed as a standalone?

No, because that's not what's happening.  The following two code blocks are more or less identical, barring the tiny bit of extra memory for the `var`

```
function Implied() {
    B(A());
}
```

and

```
function Explicit() {
    var retA = A();
    B(retA);
}
```

In both cases, `A` is being called from the parent function, and not by `B`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do that, but you do have a couple options.

One is to simply pass other parameters.  This is what you probably should be doing.

Another option is to use `call()` or `apply()` to set the value of `this`.

```
function B() {
    var context = 'some value';
    A.call(context);  // `this` inside of A will be set to the value of context
}
```